# Plug-in Ristritto Image Viewer with Mozilla Firefox

Tags: 12.04, firefox, bug-reporting, mozilla

In xubuntu , There is an application RISTRITTO to view images. I want to plug in this application with mozilla firefox to view any images preview in Mozilla browser. How can I plug-in.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very sorry to say but you can not embed this application in Firefox . Neither as a plug-in still in some other way.

Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news. ***;)***

Comment: So can you just tell me how can I preview with out any download in firefox

Comment: Directly in Firefox. Do you have an URL for this image?